# Emulator disconnected with the error ASSERTION FAILURE

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm developing an android application which contains over twenty activities. Yesterday, when I'm running my application it works properly without any hindrance. But now when I'm running my application the emulator was disconnected and it shows the following logcat error:

```
SDKCtl sensors: Unexpected I/O status 2 in the dispatcherPANIC: ASSERTION FAILURE (external/qemu/android/sdk-controller-socket.c:1680) in _on_sdkctl_io_dispatcher_io
emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.app.main activity launch'!
```

I've searched over the Internet to find the reason for this error, but I couldn't found any clear solution. Can anyone tell why this error occured?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try activity testing

Comment: How do i try activity testing?

Comment: wait i will attached the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened unexpectedly. Try

```
project->clean
```

and refresh your project by right clicking it and choose refresh and run again. It will work